# Apache Camel - Failing FTP Component

Tags: java, ftp, apache-camel, esb

I made wrote a little piece of camel to consume a ftp server.

But after it was running for some time, it throws an exception, keeps running but doesn't consume anything any more. Also when I start it again and there are a larger number of file waiting to be consumed it will crash again. I already added an exception handler but it seems like is doesn't catch the exceptions.

This is the exception I receive:

```
Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - File operation failed: 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for 2386442.XML(3895 bytes).
Accept timed out. Code: 150]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: File operation failed: 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for 2386442.XML(3895 bytes).
Accept timed out. Code: 150
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.retrieveFileToStreamInBody(FtpOperations.java:336)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.retrieveFile(FtpOperations.java:297)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:333)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:136)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:560)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1442)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.retrieveFileToStreamInBody(FtpOperations.java:328)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot retrieve file: GenericFile[2386448.XML] from: Endpoint[ftp://1.1.1.1?delay=15000&delete=true&disconnect=true&exclude=((?i).*pdf$)&password=******&username=user]
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot retrieve file: GenericFile[2386448.XML] from:   Endpoint[ftp://1.1.1.1?delay=15000&delete=true&disconnect=true&exclude=((?i).*pdf$)&password=******&username=user]
   at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processExchange(GenericFileConsumer.java:338)
  at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.RemoteFileConsumer.processExchange(RemoteFileConsumer.java:94)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.processBatch(GenericFileConsumer.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:136)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:140)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:92)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

And this is the route I made using the Java DSL:

```
    // XML Predicate
    // only allows names without spaces
    Predicate xmlPredicate = header(RssUtils.CAMEL_FILE_NAME).regex(
            "([\\S]+(\\.(?i)(xml))$)");
    // Images Predicate
    // only allows names without spaces
    Predicate imgPredicate = header(RssUtils.CAMEL_FILE_NAME).regex(
            "([\\S]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif))$)");

    onException(SchemaValidationException.class).to(
            "file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR)
                    + "/errors/SchemaValidationException");

    onException(GenericFileOperationFailedException.class).to(
            "file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR)
                    + "/errors/GenericFileExceptions");

    from(
            "ftp://"
                    + props.getProperty(RssUtils.FTP_URL)
                    + "?username="
                    + props.getProperty(RssUtils.FTP_USER)
                    + "&password="
                    + props.getProperty(RssUtils.FTP_PWD)
                    + "&disconnect=true&delete=true&exclude=((?i).*pdf$)&delay="
                    + props.getProperty(RssUtils.FTP_DELAY))
            .choice()
            .when(xmlPredicate)
            .to("jms:xmlQueue")
    .to("jms:archiveQueue")
            .when(imgPredicate)
            .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR) + "/img")
            .otherwise()
            .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR)
                    + "/errors/other");

    from("jms:xmlQueue").to("validator:FtpXmlValidator.xsd")
            .to("xslt://XmlToRssConverter.xsl")
            .process(rssFeedProcessor)
            .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR) + "/rss/");

from("jms:archiveQueue")
    .to("file://" + props.getProperty(RssUtils.ROOT_DIR) + "/archive/");
```

Is there anything I can do to avoid this kind af behavior? It is really difficult to test so I'm hoping somebody spots a flaw in my code. I have searching for quite some time now but I don't find anything solid. Maybe some way I could debug this issue?

There maybe a few things that I found somebody could give his tought on:

- use handled(true) when using the onException
- can I set the max batch size of the consumer? (can I use throttle for this ?)
- use explicit try catch finally because I'm using the Java DSL

Don't shoot me if I'm saying anything wrong here, I just learning Camel.
So if anybody has suggestions on the code above I would appreciate it!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is an FTP issue, the fact that it is occurring in Apache Camel is largely irrelevant.

The telltale part of the bomb is:

> at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:408)
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:462)
>       at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:430)
>       at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.*openDataConnection*(FTPClient.java:560)

The [openDataConnection](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/1.4.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.java#FTPClient._openDataConnection_%28int%2Cjava.lang.String%29) method of org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient is there to support active mode FTP - passive mode just uses the same port as for commands, so it doesn't need a separate port connection.

Try switching to passive mode (passiveMode = true with Apache Camel).

Answer (score 0):

On the surface, without looking at WHY your route is failing, it sounds like what you're looking to do is [handle and continue](http://camel.apache.org/exception-clause.html)--i.e., handle this exception and continue your route where you left off. Per the documentation:

> **Available as of Camel 2.3**
>   In Camel 2.3 we introduced a new option `continued` which allows you to both **handle** and **continue** routing in the original route as if the exception did not occur.
>
> For instance to just ignore and continue if the IDontCareException was thrown we can do this:

```
onException(IDontCareException).continued(true);
```

What happens here is:

> Camel will catch the exception and . . . just ignore it and continue routing in the original route. However . . . it will route that [onException] route first, before it will continue routing in the original route.

Give this a try and it may solve your problem. As I implied, above, depending on what your root issue is, this may be more of a bandaid than a proper solution. The better approach might be to figure out why the FTP consumer is failing. At a glance, it appears that it can't find the file named `2386448.XML`.

Once you determine the root cause, you can use a `choice` to behave differently at the right time as in:

```
.choice()
    .when(isValidFtpResponse())
         .to(DIRECT_CONTINUE_FTP_ROUTE)
    .otherwise()
        .setBody(constant(null))
        .log(ERROR, "FTP failed: ${headers}")
.end()
```

Hopefully, that gives you a few ideas and helps you get passed this issue.